# Об упорядоченном индивидууме

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

Поток воды, уровень отражения, образ жизни, набор значений, перечень вещей, — понятия, к которым применимо такое свойство, как «упорядоченный». Правомерно ли будет отнести его не к черте, характеру чего-либо или кого-либо, а к личности (статусу, профессии), как в этих примерах?

> Не потому, что был упорядоченный человек, просто сам себя регулировал
> таким образом, чтобы не выпить слишком много. [Алексей Слаповский. 100
> лет спустя. Письма нерожденному сыну // «Волга», 2009]
>
> ... Из него вышел бы писатель более спокойный и упорядоченный, и мы
> имели бы ряд его романов, повестей и проч. [Н.К. Михайловский. Г.И.
> Успенский как писатель и человек (1886)]

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это авторская метафора, напрямую неприменимо:

> Этот человек как упорядоченный текст. Такой же закономерный, логичный,
> взвешенный, системный, гармоничный, правильный.

Comment: Хороший пример. Не все метафоры, но половина точно.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что такое употребление вполне возможно (даже без метафоричности).
По отношению к индивиду обычно используется в значении *размеренный, организованный, собранный.*

...«Я как мать» ― веселая, чистая, здоровая, живая, **упорядоченная**, счастливая, наслаждающаяся, многообразная, поощряемая, приятная, конкретная, сильная... [Е. А. Тетерлева, С. А. Минюрова. Диалогический подход к анализу смыслового переживания материнства // «Вопросы психологии», 2003.07.22]

*Никогда прежде она не видела, чтобы столь **упорядоченное существо** двигалось с такой быстротой и выглядело настолько встревоженным* (Д. Шерман, Д. Крэгг. Испытание джедаев).

*Впервые в жизни его **упорядоченная личность** показалась ему грубой и поношенной, потому что ему внезапно довелось преклонить колени пред алтарем самой свежести* (Ф. С. Фицджеральд. Нежные юноши).

*С другой стороны, сам Космос рассматривается как некий живой и одушевленный, совершенно **упорядоченный организм**, подчиненный ритму и закону* (Е. Бадрина. Проклятья древних цивилизаций).

Comment: В каждой строчке... Не о матери упорядоченной, а «как матери», т.е. о представлении; не прямо — о человеке, а о существе, организме, «его» упорядоченной личности.